# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el valor de un FormSelect?

Tags: jquery, materialize

Este es el HTML del select, está hecho con Materializecss.

```
                <div class="col l4 s4">
                    {!! Form::label('tipo_diagnostico', 'Tipo Diagnóstico:') !!}
                    <select name="tipo_diagnostico" id="tipo_diagnostico">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>-- Seleccione tipo de diagnóstico --</option>
                        <option value="impresion_dianostica">Impresión Diagnóstica</option>
                        <option value="confirmado_nuevo">Confirmado Nuevo</option>
                        <option value="confirmado_repetido">Confirmado Repetido</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Yo necesito modificar con JQuery el valor del select, pero a pesar de que se cambia el valor del select, no se muestra la nueva opción. Según parece en la documentación de materializecss es un FormSelect, pero no encuentro mucha documentación al respecto del FormSelect.

Lo que intento es esto, pero a pesar de que el valor del select cambia, no se refleja en la vista.

```
$('#tipo_diagnostico').val('confirmado_nuevo');
```

Y esto es lo que se ve en el inspeccionar elemento del navegado:

[image: Inspeccionar elemento navegador]

Comment: Por favor añade también el JS en donde realizas el cambio con JQuery. Saludos.

Comment: Saludos. Esta en inglés pero parece incluye ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341095/change-value-of-materialize-select-box-by-jquery y funciona que es lo mejor.

Comment: Gracias, voy probar.

Comment: Me salió un error con la función material_select(), aquí la solución: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087997/materialize-material-select-is-not-a-function-error.